# Setting a socket nonblocking after a blocking connect

Tags: c, linux, sockets, nonblocking

Is it safe to do `connect()` in blocking and after that, make the socket nonblock and do all nonblocking stuff for example `epoll()`/`select()`?

Does it cause to lack of some nonblocking operation that might I'm not considering?

Comment: No, there's no problem with doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly safe so long as you make sure to check the return value of `fnctl` for an error.  If not, then you could find your program halting unexpectedly.

Comment: *Blocking* unexpectedly.

Comment: *Blocking*, *halting* same thing when you're not in a debugger.